# JPA Select query is taking more time - beyond 60 seconds

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, yourkit

Currently we have 45 different tables in DB with 1000 records in each table. Number of parallel requests we get is 15 messages / seconds and each record in table may not exceed 100 KB.

Our situation is that we select the list of tables one after the other with a common id that we have across all the tables ex: emp.id. The select query is based on the emp.id.

When I am firing the select query for all these tables with a specific emp.id, below are the results

- @ 10 message/second - it is normal and responds back within 500 milliseconds
- @ 12 message/second- Time is growing continuously and exceeds 60 seconds

What could be going wrong? Also no blocking is identified in DB.

Below is my code

```
@PersistenceContext
            EntityManager entityManager;// = getEntityManager();

            private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryNew;//= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("srk-orm");
            protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
                            entityManager = entityManagerFactoryNew.createEntityManager();
                            return entityManager;
            }

            protected void closeEntityManager() {
                            try {
                                            if(null != entityManager) {
                                                            entityManager.close();
                                            }
                            } catch(Throwable th){}
            }


            ////
            private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListActiveEmployeesDAO.class);

            public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
                            this.entityManager = entityManager;
            }


            public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails(java.lang.Integer EmployeeId) {

                            List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
                            try {



                                            EntityGraph<Employee> EmployeeGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Employee.class);



                                            list =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT j FROM Employee j "

                                                            + "WHERE j.EmployeeId=:EmployeeId and j.statusCode=:statusCode " , Employee.class)
                                                                            .setParameter("statusCode", 'A')
                                                                            .setParameter("EmployeeId", EmployeeId)
                                                                            .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", EmployeeGraph)
                                                                            .setLockMode(LockModeType.NONE)
                                                                            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_READONLY,true)
                                                                            .getResultList();


                                            LOGGER.debug("Employee list size for Single Employee: {}",list.size());








                            } catch(Throwable th) {

                            } finally {
                                            closeEntityManager();
                            }


                            return list;

            }

            public List<EmployeeRoute> getEmployeeRoute(java.lang.Integer EmployeeId){

                            List<EmployeeRoute> list=new ArrayList<EmployeeRoute>();
                            try
                            {
                                            //We will create EntityGraph dynamically
                                            EntityGraph<EmployeeRoute> EmployeeRouteGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(EmployeeRoute.class);



                                            list =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT jr FROM EmployeeRoute jr "

                                                            + "WHERE  jr.Employee.EmployeeId=:EmployeeId AND jr.statusCode=:statusCode  " , EmployeeRoute.class)
                                                                            .setParameter("statusCode", 'A')
                                                                            .setParameter("EmployeeId", EmployeeId)
                                                                            .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", EmployeeRouteGraph)
                                                                            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_READONLY,true)
                                                                            .setLockMode(LockModeType.NONE)
                                                                            .getResultList();
                                            LOGGER.debug("EmployeeRoute list size for Single Employee: {}",list.size());



                            } catch(Throwable th) {

                            } finally {
                                            closeEntityManager();
                            }

                            return list;
            }
```

Below is my applicationContext.xml for JPA.

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"    
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
              
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
              
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.uil.employee.orm.*" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.uil.employee.orm.dao.*" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.uil.employee.orm.util.*" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.uil.employee.orm.db.*" />
       <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="srk-orm.properties"/> -->
       <context:annotation-config/>
       
       <cache:annotation-driven />
       
       <task:annotation-driven executor="ormTaskExecutor" />
    <task:executor id="ormTaskExecutor" pool-size="${orm.task.executor.initialsize}-${orm.task.executor.maxTotal}" queue-capacity="${orm.task.executor.queueCapacity}" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
       
       <bean
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

       <!-- ************ JPA configuration *********** -->
       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />  
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="srk-esb-orm" />        
        <property name="dataSource" ref="srkDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.uil.employee.orm.*" />
        <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
           Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
                
          
            </bean>
        </property>
              

    </bean>     
    
    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run profiler's I see below

```html
    ormTaskExecutor-251  Blocked CPU usage on sample: 0ms
  java.lang.Class.forName0(String, boolean, ClassLoader, Class) Class.java (native)
  java.lang.Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) Class.java:348
  org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(String) ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226
  org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstantValue(String, ClassLoaderService) ReflectHelper.java:235
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl$JavaConstantConverter.handleDotStructure(AST) QueryTranslatorImpl.java:615
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl$JavaConstantConverter.visit(AST) QueryTranslatorImpl.java:610
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(AST) NodeTraverser.java:60
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(AST) NodeTraverser.java:49
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(boolean) QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(Map, boolean, String) QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187
  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(Map, boolean) QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142
  org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(String, String, boolean, Map, SessionFactoryImplementor, EntityGraphQueryHint) HQLQueryPlan.java:115
  org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(String, boolean, Map, SessionFactoryImplementor, EntityGraphQueryHint) HQLQueryPlan.java:81
  org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.applyEntityGraphQueryHint(EntityGraphQueryHint) AbstractQueryImpl.java:1056
  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list() QueryImpl.java:604
  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList() QueryImpl.java:483
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor565.invoke(Object, Object[])
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[]) Method.java:498
  org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.getResultList()
```

Comment: Have you checked the datasource/connection pool settings? Could be that you just hit the max number of active connections.

Comment: initalSize is 64 and maxTotal is 512. Won't that be enough?

Comment: Please post your POJOs